# Repair GRUB from Arch live CD

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Arch on `sda8` (with swap on `sda7`) following the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Wired_2). I got to the part of setting up the WiFi a second time, but since I already have GRUB, I got lost at the section about installing a bootloader. I rebooted, and GRUB opened as usual: with Ubuntu and Windows options, but no Arch. I went to Ubuntu and tried various things to get GRUB to recognise Arch (usually involving `grub-install`). However, these made things worse, and now when I reboot and select Ubuntu, I get the message:

```
error: file `/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic' not found
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

There are a few things I can still run:

- An Arch live CD
- A GParted live CD
- A LuPu live CD
- A Wubi version of Ubuntu 13.04 (Ubuntu running from the Windows partition `sda2`)
- Probably, by extension, Windows (I haven't tried yet)

I'd rather not install another large live CD, since they take a very long time to download. So, how can I recover use of the actual Ubuntu 14.04 and get access to Arch?

---

**Edit**: I can now use Arch and Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you run grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg after installing grub in order to generate the new config file?

Comment: I remember doing `grub-mkconfig` but I'll try again. Which OS should I run it on (Arch live CD/Wubi/...)?

Comment: I ran it on Wubi, and it said promising things like “Found Ubuntu 14.04” and “Found Arch”, but after reboot things are just the same. Same options, can't access Ubuntu 14.04 &c.

Comment: Did you mount all partitions?  And (dumb question, but…) did you redirect the `grub-mkconfig`'s output to the right file?

Comment: No. I'll try mounting all of the partitions when I get back to that computer. The command I ran was `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, which I'm hoping is the correct file, but I can't know at the moment. How do I tell whether it's right?

Comment: Okay, before I get back home, what's the best order to do things in? 1) mount all of the partitions. 2) `grub-mkconfig`. 3) `grub-install` (is that necessary?)? Also, do I need to mount swap partitions?

Comment: Okay, I've got some weird system now by which, to boot Arch, I select Windows 7 from GRUB, which takes me to the Windows bootloader. From that, I pick Ubuntu (Wubi), which actually takes me to another GRUB menu. From that, I can pick Wubi, Ubuntu 14.04 or Arch. So I can get to Arch and real Ubuntu, but I must be putting the output into the wrong file. I still have no idea which partition that file is on, and changing the boot partition doesn't make a difference. Is there anything more I can show you?